# Adding new fonts in TCPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

Does anybody can help me how to install or add new font in **TCPDF**. I already got the `.z`,`php` and `.ttf` file in my font. And how to display or use the font.. I stored the given file into fonts folder.
I used **CodeIgniter**.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the below thing. If you have .ttf file for the new font then convert that font to .php and .z files using below link
http://www.xml-convert.com/en/convert-tff-font-to-afm-pfa-fpdf-tcpdf

Once you converted the fonts download the .php and .z file and upload it into tcpdf's fonts folder. TCPDF will consider your filename as your fontname so make sure you have correct file names.

Once files are uploaded you can directly use setfont function of tcpdf.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this?

https://tcpdf.org/docs/fonts/

something like this should work I think.

```
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('/path-to-font/DejaVuSans.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
```

Comment: I tried that but it display nothing. i think there`s an error.

Comment: @LeorahSumarong consider posting out the error. I doubt that a solution straight from official documentation doesn't work becasue of library issue...

Comment: The problem is there is no error message at all. It`s just a white page

Comment: have you checked log files for php? and error reporting is turned on? ```error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);```

Comment: this works like charm. the online conversion given as correct answer doesn't work for me

Comment: This url doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

**TCPDF: How to add new custom font in tcpdf**

1. Download required font's ttf file
2. Open http://www.fpdf.org/makefont website in the browser and upload the ttf font on this website
3. Download two files `customfontname.php` and `customfontname.z`
4. Copy these two files into `/yourproject/vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/fonts/` folder
5. include / set the font in your script before tcpdf html code `$pdf->SetFont('customfontname', '', 12);`

Comment: This solution solved my problem and worked very well in 3 projects. Happy to share with you :)